# Get multiple roles with get_users

Tags: users

I've got some code like this:

```
$query_args = array();
$query_args['fields'] = array( 'ID', 'display_name' );
$query_args['role'] = 'subscriber';
$users = get_users( $query_args );
foreach ($users as $user) $users_array[$user->ID] = $user->display_name;
```

I want to get more roles and also include `contributor`, `author` and some custom roles I created with the Role Scoper plugin e.g. `Manager`, etc. Any ideas how I can do this with `get_users`?

Thanks

Answer (score 30):

### Fast forward to WordPress 4.4 - it will support the `role__in` attribute!

It looks like WordPress 4.4 is our **lucky version number**, because it will support both the `role__in` and `role__not_in` attributes of the `WP_User_Query` class.

So to include the *subscriber*, *contributor* and *author* roles, we can simply use:

```
$users = get_users( [ 'role__in' => [ 'subscriber', 'contributor', 'author' ] ] );
```

Check out the ticket [#22212](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22212) for the whole story!

Comment: You have been officially dubbed birgireV4.4, the new and improved version ;-)

Answer (score 19):

You can also do this via a single call to `get_users` or using a single `WP_User_Query` by making use of the `meta_query` argument:

```
global $wpdb;
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'capabilities',
            'value' => 'role_one',
            'compare' => 'like'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'capabilities',
            'value' => 'role_two',
            'compare' => 'like'
        )
    )
) );
```

The `meta_query` is pulled from how `WP_User_Query` handles the `role` parameter, if you're interested.

Comment: @Andy-Adams Thanks for sharing. This only seems to display *all* the roles for me.  Is this still working for you?

Comment: @helgatheviking What roles are you comparing, specifically? It could depend on what the role names are.

Comment: @AndyAdams I'm trying to work this into my Simple User Listing plugin, so I'm trying to make it work for any combination of roles. On my local site, I've tried administrator and editor, but looping through the results all the other roles are still included.

Comment: I might recommend using the Debug Queries plugin to see what SQL query is being generated. A lot of times this helps me figure out why I'm getting unexpected results. http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-queries/

Answer (score 13):

I managed to solve this by using this function:

```
function get_clients() { 

    $users = array();
    $roles = array('subscriber', 'custom_role1', 'custom_role2');

    foreach ($roles as $role) :
        $users_query = new WP_User_Query( array( 
            'fields' => 'all_with_meta', 
            'role' => $role, 
            'orderby' => 'display_name'
            ) );
        $results = $users_query->get_results();
        if ($results) $users = array_merge($users, $results);
    endforeach;

    return $users;
}
```

Then in my theme I can do this:

```
$users_array = get_clients();
```

Comment: This is the best option I have come across. Thanks.

Comment: @blogjunkie Curious, but how well does this sort?

Answer (score 4):

```
$users = array_merge( get_users('role=subscriber'), get_users('role=contributor') );
```

Since `get_users()` returns an array of users that match the query string given as a param. Just run the `get_users()` query for every role you want separately and merge the results. You can then loop through `$users` the same way you would have otherwise.

Comment: Can you please provide more information explaining why this solves the problem?

Comment: I edited the original answer to better explain why it works.

Comment: I used this as `$users = array_merge(  get_users( array('role' => 'RoleOne' ,'fields' => 'ID') ),  get_users( array('role' => 'RoleTwo' ,'fields' => 'ID') ));`, and it worked a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with using `array_merge` is that you can't use pagination.  I really like @Andy Adams's solution, but if you're searching on many roles, using his meta query will result in a **very slow** query (internally it does a new `INNER JOIN` for each meta query).

My solution is to use a regular expression meta query:

```
<?php

global $wpdb;
$blog_id = get_current_blog_id();

$roles = array('editor', 'administrator');
$meta_query = array(
    'key' => $wpdb->get_blog_prefix($blog_id) . 'capabilities',
    'value' => '"(' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $roles)) . ')"',
    'compare' => 'REGEXP'
);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query(array(
    'meta_query' = array($meta_query)
));

?>
```

This generates a query that looks something like:

```
array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'wp_capabilities'
            'value' => '"(editor|administrator)"'
            'compare' => 'REGEXP'
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply merge more user query results. Let's say you want to include both `Author` and `Editor` roles. Define the query for each case then use [array_merge](http://php.net/array_merge) to consolidate into a single array.

```
$xuser_query = new WP_user_query(array( 'role' => 'Author'));    
$yuser_query = new WP_user_query(array( 'role' => 'Editor'));
$mergedRoles=array_merge($xuser_query->results,$xuser_query->results);

// further on you might want to do some sorting 
// of the resulting array of objects before looping through it:

if (!empty( $mergedRoles->results ) ) {
 foreach ( $mergedRoles->results as $user ) { 
        echo $user->display_name;
      }
 else echo "nada, no users found";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can use this easy way

```
$admins = get_users( array(
    'role__in'     => array('administrator', 'editor', 'author'),
    'fields' => array( 'ID' ),
) );
$admins_ids = wp_list_pluck( $admins, 'ID' );

$users = get_users(array(
    'exclude' => $admins_ids,
    'fields' => array( 'ID' ),
    ) );
$users_ids = wp_list_pluck( $users, 'ID' );
```

Answer (score 0):

All the parameters from the function [get_users](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) are optional. If you specify nothing you will get an array that contains objects corresponding to each and every user of the current blog, including ones with custom roles.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$xuser_query = new WP_user_query(array( 'role' => 'Author'));    
$yuser_query = new WP_user_query(array( 'role' => 'Editor'));

$mergedRoles=array_merge($xuser_query->results,$xuser_query->results);

// further on you might want to do some sorting 
// of the resulting array of objects before looping through it:

if (!empty( $mergedRoles) ) {

    foreach ( $mergedRoles as $user ) { 
        echo $user->display_name;
    }

} else {
    echo "nada, no users found";
}
?>
```