# How to fetch WP_User_Query with multiple role arguments

Tags: meta-query, wp-user-query

I have two user role

1) vendor 2)freevendor

Here i am trying to fetch user by there user role `vendor` and `freevendor` with the bellow code but query is fetching only `freevendor`.

```
$vendor_total_args = array (
    'role' => 'vendor',
    'role' => 'freevendor',
   'orderby'            => $orderby,
  'order'               => $order,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon',
            'value'   => $_POST[ 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon1' ],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'pv_merchant_specialization',
            'value'   => $_POST[ 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon2' ],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);
```

So how can i fetch multiple user role  `vendor` and `freevendor` using above snippet code.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/88158/22728

Comment: The problem is that the SQL `AND` clause will question if _both_ arguments apply. What you need to use is `OR` to match _both_ roles. Also, you should sanitize your `$_POST` data with PHPs `filter_input()` for e.g.. This could be unsafe data from a form request and a perfect target for a SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

`WP_User_Query` only accepts a single 'role' argument, and since your array has the same key twice only the second is getting used:

```
array(
    'role' => 'vendor',
    'role' => 'freevendor',
);
```

Is the same as:

```
array(
    'role' => 'freevendor',
);
```

You could make two calls, one for each role set:

```
$user_query_args = array (
    'role'       => 'vendor',
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key'     => 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon',
            'value'   => $_POST[ 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon1' ],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'pv_merchant_specialization',
            'value'   => $_POST[ 'pv_merchant__experiance_dropdwon2' ],
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
);

$vendors = new WP_User_Query( $user_query_args )->results;

$user_query_args['role'] = 'freevendor';

$freevendors = new WP_User_Query( $user_query_args )->results;
```

And then combine the two result sets. Or take a look at the comment that shows how to write a meta query combining the two roles.